# Having trouble with CSS absolute positing in different browsers

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I can't seem to get a box that I positioned using the position:absolute tag in CSS. In works fine in Chrome, but in FF and IE it is always higher up than it should be. How do I fix this?

Here is some of my code:

CSS:

```
#linkList .select { 
    top: 1895px; 
    background-color: #C83419; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 760px;
    padding: 10px; 
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;

}
```

Comment: can you please post a fiddle too..

Comment: Please post your HTML and related CSS.

Comment: Or a *code-snipped* (Ctrl + M | new built in feature here on SO :D )

Comment: Absolutely-positioned elements require a relatively-positioned parent, otherwise they take their position relative to the BODY tag. Are defining position:relative on a parent element?

Comment: I can tell you right now that using 1895px from the top is a recipie for disaster across resolution changes.   The ideal way to use absolute positioning is to position it as locally as possible, ie `relative` to a parent.   So in a wrapper, you would set position:relative, and the child unit could use something like `top:10px; position:absolute;` to get it to pop in the right spot.

Comment: And, you shouldn't ever need to use margins, use your spacing correctly.

Comment: You should be setting a `left` and `top` value for `.select` as browsers handle it differently. Some force them to be 0, some don't